# Call to a member function wasWithinLast() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

Trying to use the timehelper [`$this->Time->wasWithinLast($how_often, $last_updated);`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::wasWithinLast)

But I keep getting

```
Error: Call to a member function wasWithinLast() on a non-object
```

It seems like it can't find `$this->Time`? Is that correct?

`$how_often` and `$last_updated` are both in the correct format.

**SOLUTION:**
Here is the solution. $this->Time only works in view. Here is how it works in model:

```
CakeTime::wasWithinLast($how_often, $last_updated);
```

---

This is the beginning of my reminders controller:

```
class RemindersController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        var_dump($this->Time);
        $this->Reminder->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('reminders', $this->Paginator->paginate());

    }
```

Here is the model:

```
class Reminder extends AppModel {


    public function beforeSave($options = array())
  {
    // Attribute to this user
    $this->data['Reminder']['user_id'] = AuthComponent::user('id');
    $this->data['Reminder']['how_often'] = $this->data['Reminder']['number'].' '.$this->data['Reminder']['frame'];
    $this->data['Reminder']['last_reminded'] = $this->data['Reminder']['created'];



  }

  public $virtualFields = array(
    'remindable' => 'Reminder.created'
);

   public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){

    parent::afterFind($results, $primary);


    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
$results[$key]['Reminder']['remindable'] = $this->remindable($results[$key]['Reminder']['how_often'], $results[$key]['Reminder']['last_reminded']);

        // $results[$key]['Reminder']['remindable'] = $this->Time->wasWithinLast($results[$key]['Reminder']['how_often'], $results[$key]['Reminder']['last_reminded']);

// $results[$key]['Comments']


    }


    // $results = Set::sort($results, '{n}.Item.score', 'desc');

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily that it can't find the property `$Time`, it's that it isn't an object.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the arguments are valid or not, `$this->Time` is a null value

Comment: So I'm not clear on how to use $this->Time->wasWithinLast. As an out-of-the-box helper this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @itamar, where was Class `$this->Time` represents instantiated in your class?  Use var_dump to see the actual value.

Comment: @MarkBaker but $this->Time is referring to TimeHelper, no? Which should work fine. I have used $this->Time->timeAgoInWords before with no issue.

Comment: From where in your code are you calling this? In a controller?

Comment: @Devon Okay - `var_dump($this->Time)` returns NULL. So I guess I need to understand how to include the TimeHelper in the app.

Comment: Show the code around this, that might give somebody an idea.

Comment: @mopo922 - good idea. Added some code.

Comment: I don't know enough about cakephp, it looks like mopo922 answered correctly.  $this->Time is only an instance of TimeHelper in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#namespace-Cake\I18n

"If you need `TimeHelper` functionalities outside of a View..."

```
$time = new Time('2014-06-15'); // your custom date here
$time->wasWithinLast($how_often, $last_updated);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#comparing-with-intervals

Comment: The question is not about CakePHP 3.x, you may want to update your answer and show how it's done with 2.x